# How to get values from Java file to JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp

In my code, I am storing values in string array and want to display these array values in my JSP page. I tried to use session and `setArrtibute` property as well but it does't work.

```
if (button.equals("Finish")) {
    pname[n] = request.getParameter("name");
    pemail[n] = request.getParameter("email");

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/invite2.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    n++;
}
```

invite2.jsp

```jsp
<form method="get" name="create" action="MainController">

    <h2>Invite participants</h2>
    <h3> you invited </h3>

    <ul><li> </li>
        <li></li>
        <li> </li>
    </ul>

    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Cancel" style="height:30px; width:120px">
    </input>

    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Confirm" style="height:30px; width:120px">
    </input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<c:out value="${sessionScope.att1}"/>
<c:out value="${requestScope.att2}"/>
```

to access (print) the content of a session or request attribute. You would have to set them before `forward()`. (If it is a purely request specific value, you would not use session):

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("att1", "hello");
request.setAttribute("att2", "world");
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/invite2.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

[This turorial](http://wiki4.caucho.com/Java_EE_Servlet/JSP_tutorial:_Building_a_simple_listing_in_JSP) describes the whole process in detail. Including the JSP side to format a table for a list of beans (representing Books).

Comment: Thank you but in jsp page when i insert <c:out value="${sessionScope.att1}"/> and <c:out value="${requestScope.att2}"/> then this statement shows error that insert assignment operator expression to complete assisgnment